# Which actions a non-root process can't do?

Tags: linux, capabilities

Obviously, it can not rwx files that it doesn't have permission to. But I am talking about other "actions", I know of them is binding to ports with lower number than 1024. What else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-privileged processes can’t do a lot of things; on Linux, [`man 7 capabilities`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) contains a comprehensive list.

Examples beyond your two include:

- controlling auditing;
- setting up BPF;
- changing file ownership to arbitrary values;
- opening raw sockets;
- changing to arbitrary users and groups;
- setting up arbitrary namespaces;
- loading or unloading kernel modules;
- rebooting.

Note that on Linux, all this isn’t controlled only by `root`, but also by capabilities, so subsets of these privileges can be granted to non-`root` processes. There are also other mechanisms to request a privileged process to perform a privileged operation on behalf of a non-privileged user (*e.g.* rebooting).